# ActionCable.server => ' /cable' within authenticated_rooth_path only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5

Consider the following scenario:

**1) WebSocket authenticates the connection.**

```
def connect
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
  logger.add_tags "ActionCable", "User #{current_user.id}"
end
```

**2) When connection is established, inform the user**

```
  connected: ->
    $("body").append("<div class='connection ok'>Connected.</div>")
```

**3) When connection is lost, inform the user**

```
  disconnected: ->
    $("pop-up").append("<div class='connection'>Offline, trying to reconnect...</div>")
```

**4) When user logs out.....**

```
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
###User is now informed connection is lost. Which should not happen.
```

**My question:** How can I change:

```
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

To **only** work within the scope of:

```
 authenticated :user do
   root 'users#index', as: :authenticated_root
 end
```

Comment: "An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected" happens because most likely your `find_verified_user` has a code: `reject_unauthorized_connection unless current_user`. This may be either intentional or not: that is, do you allow non-signed-in users to also subscribe to the channel? Then you'll need to remove `reject_unauthorized_connection`. This will leave `current_user` to become `nil` if signedout; if you wish to still identify the current user even if non-signed-in, you can also add another identifier: `identified_by: :session_id`, and you set it by `self.session_id = request.session.id`

Comment: Ahh.. That's why. I thought that it'd just automatically exclude current_user if non was found. Thanks.

Comment: no problem!! :D

Comment: You can wrap it up in an answer and I'll give it to you. I know it doesn't answer the question, but still – should be an accepted answer.

Comment: alright then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative Solution

> An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected

...happens when `reject_unauthorized_connection` is called in your `connection.rb`.

- This may be either **intentional** or **not**:

  - remove `reject_unauthorized_connection` if you want to allow non-signed-users to subscribe to the channel: `current_user` becomes `nil`

    - To be able to still identify the user, you can add another identifier (`:session_id`) :

      ```
      module ApplicationCable
        class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
          identified_by :current_user
          identified_by :session_id

          def connect
            self.current_user = find_verified_user
            self.session_id = request.session.id
          end

          private

          def find_verified_user
            User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
          end
      # ...
      ```
    - You may want to write your own authorisation in your *_channel.rb instead of here in the connection.rb if you'll need further authorisation rules between guest and signed-in users.
  - retain `reject_unauthorized_connection` if you only want signed-in users to be able to subscribe to your channels.

Comment: Thanks Jay-Ar, really appreciate it.

Comment: glad to help :)